# c# console app as service

Tags: service, cmd

Just a simple consloe app that I want to have running as a service at all times, don't have the VB template.

So far I have:

- given highestAvailable permission in the manifest, and bound the manifest in properties
- right clicked on exe compatibility and selected "run as admin"
- opened security settings so "everyone", administrators, services, system, network services, local services and some users all have permission for full access.
- successfully added to service list with this code, code is run from separate solution form, also running with manifest and as admin:

  ```
  private static void cmd_PROMPT(string cmd)
  {
      ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
      cmdStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
      cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
      cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
      cmdStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
      cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      cmdStartInfo.Arguments = "/user:Administrator ";

      Process cmdProcess = new Process();
      cmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
      cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += cmd_Error;
      cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += cmd_DataReceived;
      cmdProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
      cmdProcess.Start();
      cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
      cmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

      cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmd);    
      MessageBox.Show(">>" + cmd);
      //cmdProcess.WaitForExit();
  }


  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string s;
      string prgmName = "@QU@Service";
      string prgmPath = "c:\\@QU@\\aquaService.exe";
      string prgmMode = "auto"; 
      s = "sc create " + prgmName + " binpath= " + prgmPath + " DisplayName= \"" + prgmName + "\" start= " + prgmMode;

      cmd_PROMPT(s);
  }
  ```

The app has made it in to the service list in control panel but it is "stopped"... when I click ...action... start service, it tries but fails with `error:1053 did not start in timely fashion`.
When I use CMD instruction it changes to "starting" in the service list, but then goes right back to stop:

```
         prgmName = "@QU@Service";
         prgmPath = "c:\\@QU@\\aquaService.exe";
         prgmMode = "auto";
         s = "sc start " + prgmName;
         cmd_PROMPT(s);
```

Comment: Services have to follow certain rules. They have to interact with the Service Controller. It has to be written as a service. Use Task Scheduler if running a normal exe. Windows Resource Kits have a program called Svcany that is a service that will run an exe. It handles communication with windows so the Service Controller will be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ty Noodles, with your clue I was able to get this code working:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s;
        string prgmName = "@QU@Service";
        string prgmPath = "c:\\@QU@\\aquaService.exe";
        string prgmMode = "auto";
        string _subKey = "Parameters";
        string keyName = "Application";
        RegistryKey _baseRegistryKey;
        s = "C:\\@QU@\\instsrv.exe " + prgmName + " C:\\@QU@\\srvany.exe";
        cmd_PROMPT(s);
        s = "sc config " + prgmName + " start=auto ";   //   boot 
        cmd_PROMPT(s);
        try
        {
            _baseRegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services", true);
            var sk1 = _baseRegistryKey.CreateSubKey(prgmName);
            _baseRegistryKey = sk1; sk1 = _baseRegistryKey.CreateSubKey(_subKey); 
            if (sk1 != null) { sk1.SetValue(keyName.ToUpper(), prgmPath, RegistryValueKind.String); }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" " + ee, "Administrator");
        }              
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        prgmName = "@QU@Service";
        prgmPath = "c:\\@QU@\\aquaService.exe";
        prgmMode = "auto";
        s = "sc start " + prgmName;
        cmd_PROMPT(s);    
    }
```